# AYUDA: Problemas al instalar Laravel Collective

Tags: laravel, composer

Buenas tardes colegas!!!.

Estoy instalando Laravel Collective pero estoy teniendo problemas para ello.

Si uso el comando que proporcionan en la página oficial:

**composer require "laravelcollective/html":"^5.4.0"**

Me general el siguiente error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego leyendo en algunos sites recomendaban cambiar las comillas dobles por simples, quedando la línea de la siguiente manera:

**composer require 'laravelcollective/html:^5.4.0'**

Y me genera este error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por lo visto es por incompatibilidad de versiones... Como podría solucionar esto amigos???

Answer (score 0):

La documentación oficial (https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.4/html) indica que el primer comando era el correcto:

```
composer require "laravelcollective/html":"^5.4.0"
```

Damos por entendido que la versión de laravel es la 5.4 (lo digo porque para otras versiones el comando cambia).

Composer debería de resolver las dependencias. Te recomiendo que cambies de terminal y uses "git bash" para windows... A veces, windows powershell complica un poco la cosa ante estos tipos de comandos...